# Динамическое увеличение количества элементов списка

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, python-3.x, django

Пишу проект на django, в котором необходимо вывести список выбора элементов на страницу, но так как количество элементов достаточно большое, то загрузка происходит долго.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы варианты выбора в `select` подгружались частями при скролинге? Подозреваю, что надо использовать ajax , но не знаю как 
(если не сложно, то с примерным кодом, ибо в js и ajax новичок).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/TerryZ/SelectPage - селект с пагинацией.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax при наборе он погружает список с сервера. Возможно подойдет.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: мб и подойдет, но я не знаю как под себя переделать, так как мне нужно расширение списка, и сам по себе список не выпадающий....

Comment: @ddsds добавил еще одну ссылочку выше с select, имеющим пагинацию.